# Oracle: select items in CSV format?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

Suppose I had a query

```
select name from tbl where dept = 123
```

which returns a data set like this

```
bob
carol
steve
```

Is there a way of natively expressing (in sql, or perhaps a procedure?) a query which will return the data as a CSV or space separated list?

```
bob,carol,steve
```

Comment: heh you had asked a similar question couple years ago :) [Oracle: normalized fields to CSV string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1441971)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of Oracle?

Tim Hall has a page describing various [string aggregation techniques in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php).  If you are using Oracle 11.2, the simplest option is

```
SELECT listagg(name, ',') within group( order by name)
  FROM table_name
 WHERE dept = 123
```

If you are using earlier versions of Oracle, there are many other approaches with various advantages and disadvantages.  Tim's comparison of the various approaches is pretty complete.